# Getting total height of an element?

Tags: jquery

What's the right way to get the total height of a div element? I'm trying this:

```
element.outerHeight(true);
```

but when I take a screenshot of my page, and measure the height (in pixels) of the element, it seems to be a few pixels taller than what element.outerHeight() is reporting. Is there a different way? I'd like to include all padding/margin in my height.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any JS library? jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include the padding and border use outerHeight(false), if you want to include padding, border and margin use outerHeight(true) and if you want to include only the height of the element use height().

Comment: Yes, but this is a jQuery function, and the syntax is: `$(element).outerHeight(false);` See http://jqapi.com/#p=outerHeight for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) method instead:

```
 $('#element').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Comment: Right, but that obviously doesn't answer the question.